# Difference between (import module_name) and (from module_name import *)

Tags: python, module, python-import

Whats is the difference between import module_name and from module_name import *. As I read, both imports all functions from the module

Comment: Not a duplicate of that specific question. Note the wildcard.

Comment: Read the answers on the dupe.  It's a duplicate question.